# How to handle fragments in android singleactivity design pattern?

Tags: android

In my Android App I am using the SingleActivity Design Pattern. On my home page I have a button. When it clicks another fragment will open. I then want the original button to disappear and wondered what the right approach is. Do I just hide the button in that case? Or do I delete it (and reinitialize the button when the user gets back to the home page?

Comment: Why don't just yourButton.setVisibility(GONE)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set button visibility to `View.GONE` to avoid creating the same component many times.